# Inserting info in a MATLAB graph

Tags: matlab

Hey I've started an assignment on matlab, I need to find function's solution. So the code is working well and when I put a graph into it, it shows me the graph. My problem is when I try , but when I'm trying to figure out how to present the cordinates of a point like I marked in the pic, I get lost. Can anybody help me please?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Keep trying. Stack Overflow requires you to put effort into your question, and to *show that effort*, see [ask]. If you're planning on asking more question here, I can recommend [Jon Skeet's blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) on asking questions, that teaches you all the things you need to consider when asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the data in `x` and `y` and the point of interest is at index `x(n)` and `y(m)`

```
figure
plot(x,y)
text(x(n),y(m),['(' num2str(x(n)) ',' num2str(y(m)) ')'])
```

To add the dashed lines to the point

```
plot([0 x(n)], [y(m) y(m)], [x(n) x(n)], [0 y(k)], 'r--')
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to add those lines also? The lineal I marked in the picture.

Comment: Well, what do you think, you have an x and y position, so I think you can find the other ends of the two lines, right?

Comment: I couldn't understand you. I meant the red lines.. how can I add them to the graph?

Comment: If you have a (x,y) position, how do you draw a horizontal and vertical line to that point, starting respectively from left and bottom of the figure? Just make the lines by using `plot(linedata, 'r--')`